# The value of input (text / hidden) empty in IE 11 (Edge), "back" or history.back () for second time

Tags: internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

`Forward` or `back` navigation buttons on IE 11 (Edge) of Windows 7
Or can move history with `history.forward ()`, `history.back ()`
In the first history display, the entered value is restored,
In the second history display, the value entered becomes empty.

Is this a problem of IE 11 (Edge)?

- Windows 10 (Edge) browser will do the same.
- Values are not empty up to IE 8 in compatibility mode, but values after IE 9 are empty.
- In FireFox, Chrome, Safari, Opera, the value is not empty.

### Example operation.

1. Input Form A.

   (1) Enter a value in the `<input type = "text" name = "a1" value = "">` text box.

   (2) Send by pressing `<input type = "submit" name = "send" value = "send">`, Transition to input form B occurs.
2. Input Form B.

   (1) Enter a value in the `<input type = "text" name = "a1" value = "">` text box.

   (2) Send by pressing `<input type = "submit" name = "send" value = "send">`, Transition to input form C is made.
3. Input Form C.

   (1) Enter a value in the `<input type = "text" name = "a1" value = "">` text box.

   (2) Send by pressing `<input type = "submit" name = "send" value = "send">`, Transition to input form A.
4. Input form A.

   (1) Press `back` button to input form C back.
5. Input form C ... The first history display value is displayed.

   (1) Press `back` button to return to input form B.
6. Input form B ... The first history display value is displayed.

   (1) Press `back` button to input form A back.
7. Input Form A ... The first history display value is displayed.

   (1) Press the `forward` button to enter the input form B.
8. Input Form B ... 2nd time history display, the value is empty.

   (1) Press the `forward` button to forward to the input form C.
9. Input form C ... 2nd time history display, the value is empty.

### Example Code(created with JSP).

(However, JSP statements are not used in the description code.)

```html
[history_back_test1.jsp]
 <html>
 <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
     <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" />
     <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
 </head>
 <body>
     Input form A
     <form action="history_back_test2.jsp" method="post">
         <input type="text" id="idval1" name="a1" value="">
         <br>
         <input type="submit" value="next page">
     </form>
 </body>
 </html>

[history_back_test2.jsp]
 <html>
 <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
     <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" />
     <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
 </head>
 <body>
     Input form B
     <form action="history_back_test3.jsp" method="post">
         <input type="text" id="idval1" name="a1" value="">
         <br>
         <input type="submit" value="next page">
     </form>
 </body>
 </html>

[history_back_test3.jsp]
 <html>
 <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
     <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" />
     <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
 </head>
 <body>
     Input form C
     <form action="history_back_test1.jsp" method="post">
         <input type="text" id="idval1" name="a1" value="">
         <br>
         <input type="submit" value="next page">
     </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

### Response header when the page is displayed.

```
Key             Value
State           HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server          Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type    text/html;charset=Cp943C
Content-Length  385
Date            Fri, 28 Oct 2016 08:12:54 GMT
```

Removing the value attribute of `input / type = "text"` will not empty the value.

maybe,

"The browser holds the value.
   Some flag is turned on in the first display.
   In the second and subsequent displays, the value 
   is not restored because the flag is on."

It looks like that.

I would be pleased if you can answer in person you know.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since jQuery is not used, I confirmed the effect with pure JavaScript:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    var elms = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < elms.length; i++) {
        var elm = elms[i];
        var elmType = elm.type.toLowerCase();
        if (elmType === "text" || elmType === "hidden") {
            elm.value = elm.value;
        }
    }
}, false);
```

IE 11 (Edge), IE 10 (IE 11 compatibility mode), IE 9 (IE 11 compatibility mode) OK.

There is no problem even if it operates with FireFox, Chrome, Safari, Opera.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this snip code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("input[type=text]").each(function () {
            $(this).val($(this).val());
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to keep value not to be held in the element.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    var dvs = new DelayInitValueSetter();
    function DelayInitValueSetter() {
        var delayValues = [];
        var thisRef = this;
        var p = DelayInitValueSetter.prototype;
        p.add = function(id, value) {
            var info = new Object();
            info.id = id;
            info.value = value;
            delayValues[delayValues.length] = info;
        };
        p.reset = function() {
            window.setTimeout(function() { dvs.exec(""); }, 0);
        }
        p.exec = function(dvsFlag) {
            if (dvsFlag !== "" || delayValues.length === 0) {
                return;
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < delayValues.length; i++) {
                var elm = document.getElementById(delayValues[i].id).previousElementSibling;
                elm.value = delayValues[i].value;
            }
            thisRef.completeDvsFlag();
        };
        p.getDvsFlag = function() {
            var dvsFlagElm = document.getElementsByName("dvsFlag");
            if (dvsFlagElm === void(0) || dvsFlagElm === null || dvsFlagElm.length === 0) {
                return "";
            }
            return dvsFlagElm[0].value;
        };
        p.completeDvsFlag = function() {
            var dvsFlagElm = document.getElementsByName("dvsFlag");
            if (dvsFlagElm === void(0) || dvsFlagElm === null || dvsFlagElm.length === 0) {
                return;
            }
            for (var i = 0; i < dvsFlagElm.length; i++) {
                dvsFlagElm[i].value = "completed";
            }
        };
        window.addEventListener('load', function() {dvs.exec(dvs.getDvsFlag());}, false);
    }
    -->
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    Input form A
    <form action="history_back_test2.jsp" method="post">
        <input type="text" id="idval1" name="a1"><script id="dvs1">dvs.add("dvs1","");</script>
        <input type="text" id="idval2" name="a2"><script id="dvs2">dvs.add("dvs2","123");</script>
        <input type="text" id="idval3" name="a3"><script id="dvs3">dvs.add("dvs3","ABC");</script>
        ...
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="next page">
        <input type="hidden" name="dvsFlag" disabled="disabled">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.